# Check if value exists in an object, if not return key

Tags: javascript

I would like to write a generic validation for an object that looks like this:

`const obj = { username: '', email: 'some_value', password: '' }`

I need to return in the error message a key of the item in the object that has no value.

I understand how to make it work for an individual item

```
if(!args.username){
    throw new Error(`${args.username} is a required field!`);
}
```

but it is not generic :-(

Comment: Do empty strings count as values?

Comment: @Andreas Yeah I agree, but the OP wants to iterate through *all the keys*, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
const obj = { username: '', email: 'some_value', password: '' };
for(var key of Object.keys(obj)){
  if(!obj[key]){
    throw new Error(`${key} is a required field!`);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looing each key s below

```js
var obj = { username: '', email: 'some_value', password: '' };
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    keys.forEach(function(key){
      if(!obj[key]){
        throw new Error(key+' is a required field!');
      }
    })
```